# Find a limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{\cos(\sqrt{x})}^{1}\frac{\cos(t)}{1-t}dt}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Find
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{\cos(\sqrt{x})}^{1}\frac{\cos(t)}{1-t}dt}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Substitute $y = \sqrt{x}$, by Mean Value Theorem for integrals, set $L = \lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{\cos(c)}{1-c}(1-\cos(y))}{y} = [\cos(y) \leq c \leq 1 \rightarrow 1- c \leq1-\cos(y)] = \lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{(\frac{\cos(c)\dot(1-c)}{1-c})}{y} \leq L$. We know that $0 < \cos(c) \leq \cos(1)$, thus by bounds $L \geq \lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(c)}{y} = +\infty$.

To me, the interval of integration is shrinking yet the denominator inside tends to approach $0$. How to solve it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that
$$\frac d {dx} \left(\int_{\cos(\sqrt{x})}^{1}\frac{\cos(t)}{1-t}\,dt\right)=\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \cos \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{2
   \sqrt{x} \left(1-\cos \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)}$$ Now, using L'Hospital rule, we are looking for the limit of
$$\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \cos \left(\cos
   \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{1-\cos \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}$$ Compsing Taylor series around $x=0$, we have
$$\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \cos \left(\cos
   \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{1-\cos \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{2 \cos (1)}{\sqrt{x}}+O\left(x^{1/2}\right)$$ which tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take limit as $x \to 0$ through positive values since $\sqrt x$ is involved. In the following I take limits as $y \to 0$ through positive values.

$\lim_{ y\to 0} \frac {\int_{\cos y}^{1} \frac {\cos t} {1-t} dt}y =\lim_{ y\to 0}\frac {\sin y \cos (cos y)} {1-\cos y}$ by L'Hopital's Rule. Noting that $\cos (\cos y) \to \cos 1$ as $ y \to 0$ and $\frac {\sin y } {1-\cos y}=\frac {2 \sin (y/2) \cos (y/2)} {2\sin^{2}(y/2)}=\cot (y/2)\to \infty$ we see that the givem limit is $\infty$.

Comment: How has $\sin(y)$ appeared here after applying L'Hopital? This function seem to be discontinuous at $t = 1$.

Comment: @ABC When you differentiate $\int_{\cos y}^{1}f(t)dt$ w.r.t. $y$ you get $-f(\cos y)\frac d {dy} (\cos y)$ by chain rule for differentiation.